# how to get the ino from the current folder?

Tags: linux, unix, path, pwd

How to get the ino of the current folder you actually are in, with a unix command?
or whether a man, that could be of any use could be provided..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could also use unix stat:

```
stat -c %i .
```

This will just give you the inode number.

Comment: I don't think the `stat(1)` command is portable and is not available on AIX, HPUX and Solaris at least (the question has the `unix` tag).

Comment: stat is available on HPUX, I use it everyday at work. Can't speak to AIX or Solaris.

Answer (score 3):

```
ls -id .
```

`-i` tells ls to print the inode number, `-d` says to show the directory, not the contents. `.` is the current directory.